# Spark Submit on Kuberentes exit code

Tags: kubernetes, spark-submit

How to check if the spark job is succeeded or failed programmatically, while running spark-submit. Usually the unix exit code is used.

```
 phase: Failed
 container status:
     container name: spark-kubernetes-driver
     container image: <regstry>/spark-py:spark3.2.1
     container state: terminated
     container started at: 2022-03-25T19:10:51Z
     container finished at: 2022-03-25T19:10:57Z
     exit code: 1
     termination reason: Error

2022-03-25 15:10:58,457 INFO submit.LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application Postgres-Minio-Kubernetes.py with submission ID spark:postgres-minio-kubernetes-py-b70d3f7fc27829ec-driver finished
2022-03-25 15:10:58,465 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
2022-03-25 15:10:58,466 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3321e67c-73d5-422d-a26d-642a0235cf23
```

Process failed and when I get the exit code in unix by echo $? it return a zero error code!

```
$ echo $?
0
```

The pod generated is also random way. What's the way the spark-submit is handled apart from using sparkonk8operator?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash, one way to to grep on the output. You might have to grep on [`stderr` or `stdout`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) depending on where the log output is being sent.

Something like this:

```
OUTPUT=`spark-submit ...`
if echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "exit code: 1"; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to things which @Rico mentioned, I have also considered the deployment mode of `cluster` and `client` with changing `spark-submit` shell file in $SPARK_HOME/bin directory as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

if [ -z "${SPARK_HOME}" ]; then
  source "$(dirname "$0")"/find-spark-home
fi

# disable randomized hash for string in Python 3.3+
export PYTHONHASHSEED=0



# check deployment mode.
if echo "$@" | grep -q "\-\-deploy-mode cluster";
then
    echo "cluster mode..";
    # temp log file for spark job.
    export TMP_LOG="/tmp/spark-job-log-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S').log";
    exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit "$@" |& tee ${TMP_LOG};
    # when exit code 1 is contained in spark log, then return exit 1.
    if cat ${TMP_LOG} | grep -q "exit code: 1";
    then
        echo "exit code: 1";
        rm -rf ${TMP_LOG};
        exit 1;
    else
        echo "job succeeded.";
        rm -rf ${TMP_LOG};
        exit 0;
    fi
elif echo "$@" | grep -q "\-\-conf spark.submit.deployMode=cluster";
then
    echo "cluster mode..";
    # temp log file for spark job.
    export TMP_LOG="/tmp/spark-job-log-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S').log";
    exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit "$@" |& tee ${TMP_LOG};
    # when exit code 1 is contained in spark log, then return exit 1.
    if cat ${TMP_LOG} | grep -q "exit code: 1";
    then
        echo "exit code: 1";
        rm -rf ${TMP_LOG};
        exit 1;
    else
        echo "job succeeded.";
        rm -rf ${TMP_LOG};
        exit 0;
    fi
else
    echo "client mode..";
    exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit "$@"
fi
```

Then, I have built and pushed my spark docker image.

See the following link for more details:

- https://itnext.io/things-to-consider-to-submit-spark-jobs-on-kubernetes-766402c21716